# jQuery onclick float left and return back

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, onclick

I have this javascript code written and the when you click on the info panel... It should float the `address` div to the center using the addressmoved.

**Issues**

When I click on the trigger button, instead of the `address` div floating to the center, it goes to the button of the next contents, which shouldn't happen. Also, when you click on the trigger button to close the info panel, the address div should go back to normal.

**Question**

How can i get the address to go to the center when you click on the trigger button and also how can I get it to go back to the right position when when you click on the trigger button.
 **jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".trigger").click(function(){
        $('.address').removeClass('address').addClass('addressmoved');
        $(".panel").toggle("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
.addressmoved{
float:left;
right:0;
}

.address{
font-size: 18px;
height: 120px;
position: absolute;
right: 100px;
top: 50px;
width: 200px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="address">
  <img src="image.png" alt="mainicon" />
  <span>hellow</br>
    <em>world</em> 
  </span>
  <ul>
    <li class="icon"> 
      <img class="social" src="icon1.png " alt="icon1"/>    
      </a>      
    </li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry my english is not the best

Comment: You should really try out a fiddle

Comment: Please fix your HTML, you are missing the opening `<a>` tag...

Comment: Your html is a complete mess. An `li` tag cannot exist outside a `ol` or `ul` tag. There is a closing tag for `a`, but no begin tag exists. You have a `</br>` tag, but no such tag exists. It is either `<br>` or a proper self-closing tag `<br />`.

Comment: @Sumurai8 i only copy half of it the issue is not with the ul its with the jquery

Comment: @Luffy I need the html to picture what the problem is. This html is not valid and will cause all kind of weird problems. Please post the proper html so that people can actually help you.

Comment: @Sumurai8 i CANT add images or link to images yet... so please use below for the images


**what it looks like before you click on the info panel**
[1]

**what it looks like after you click on the info panel**
[2]

**WHAT IT `SHOULD` LOOK LIKE**
[3]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/npqBb.png
  [2]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0cVpo.png
  [3]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CTgWk.png

Comment: @Cygwinnian [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/T5SY4/1/) as u can see here when u click on the info-panel it shouldn't go all the way to the left but it should stay go to the middle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T5SY4/)

Here is the **HTML** code:

```
<div class="container">
    <button id="trigger" class="button">Info panel</button>
    <div id="info-panel"></div>
</div>
```

The **CSS**

```
body, div, button {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
button:focus {
    none;
}
body {
    background: #333;
    font: 1.2em Arial, sans-serif;
}
.container {
}
.button {
    color: white;
    font: inherit;
    border-top-left-radius: 30px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: #555;
    margin: 2em 0;
    padding: 1em;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.button:hover {
    padding-right: 1.5em;
}
#info-panel {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    margin: .75em 0;
}
```

And the **JavaScript** code:

```
$("#trigger").click(function () {
    $("#info-panel").toggle("slow");
});
```

I used the `toggle` method: *This method show or hide the matched element/s.*

Comment: the info panel looks like this [Click here](http://spyrestudios.com/demos/sliding-panel-right/)

Comment: they want u do it here is that the info panel is on the top but my info panel is on the right hand side.

Comment: [this is what it should look it before clicking the info panal](http://i.stack.imgur.com/npqBb.png) [this is what it should look like after clicking the info panel]  (http://i.stack.imgur.com/CTgWk.png)

Comment: in the first image i cut out the logo sorry about that. but hopefully image 2 give u aint idea

Comment: using what u did before and now.[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/T5SY4/1/) as u can see here when u click on the info-panel it shouldn't go all the way to the left but it should stay go to the middle